# Stopping immediate right button up in Mint 13 (Cinnamon) actioning first menu choice

Tags: linux-mint

In Windows, a single right click (i.e., with release) displays a context menu on the screen, allowing you to select the appropriate choice with a further click from either button.

In Mint 13, Cinnamon, it's hold down the right button, drag, then release on the appropriate menu choice.

Both methods are fine, but constantly using both OSs regularly, I'm doing the Windows procedure in Mint by mistake all the time. This makes the single right click and release bring up the context menu and immediately action the first menu choice.

Is there any mechanism to ignore right-button-up if a substantial dragging action or time period hasn't occurred, and have Mint looking for a further click to select?

Answer (score 2):

I've solved this problem by changing string  "-GtkMenu-vertical-padding: 0;" on "-GtkMenu-vertical-padding: 1px;" in "/usr/share/themes/Mint-X/gtk-3.0/gtk-widgets.css" file.
This made a padding for top-most item in popup menu for "Mint-X" theme.

So, when I reload system and switch my theme to "Mint-X" , it is not possible to accidentally activate any menu item because there is such a padding for menu item :-)

But better way is to make your own theme, of course.